# Angularjs: jasmine-karma statement(if else path not taken)

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, test-coverage

[image]

How do I get rid out of these statements (if else path not taken) in Unit test case coverage.

Here is my spec file:

```
describe('Add Mode', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                ReactiveFormsModule,
                FormsModule,
                SharedModule,
                BootstrapModalModule,
                NgbModule.forRoot(),
                HttpClientModule
            ],
            declarations: [
                AssetAddComponent,
                FileUploadComponent
            ],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRouteAddMode },
                { provide: Router, useValue: mockRouter },
                Overlay,
                OverlayRenderer,
                SiteService,
                AuthHttp,
                MessageService,
                FileUploadService,
                LocalCacheService,
                LocalStorageService
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AssetAddComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        siteService = TestBed.get(SiteService);
        spyOn(siteService, 'getSiteAssetById')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objSiteAssetDetailById))
        spyOn(siteService, 'getSiteLocales')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objSiteLocale));
        component.ngOnInit();
        assetForm = component.assetForm;
    });

    it('should have a defined component', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('form should be invalid when in add mode', () => {
        expect(component.assetForm.valid).toBeFalsy();
    });

    it('submitting asset form', () => {
        assetForm.controls['title'].setValue('Test Asset');
        assetForm.controls['description'].setValue('This is description for Test Asset.');
        expect(assetForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
        spyOn(siteService, 'addSiteAsset')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objAddSiteAssetResponse));
        component.saveAsset();
    });

    it('updating asset form', () => {
        assetForm.controls['title'].setValue('Test Asset ew');
        assetForm.controls['description'].setValue('This is description for Test Asset.');
        expect(assetForm.valid).toBeTruthy();
        spyOn(siteService, 'updateSiteAsset')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objUpdateSiteAssetResponse));

        component.updateAsset();
    });

    it('should delete the asset', () => {
      spyOn(siteService, 'deleteSiteAsset')
            .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objSiteAssetDetailById));

        component.deleteAsset(objSiteAssetDetailById);
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(Response).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should publish the asset', () => {
        spyOn(siteService, 'updateSiteAsset')
              .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objSiteAssetDetailById));

          component.publishAsset(publish);
          fixture.detectChanges();
          expect(Response).toBeTruthy();
      });

    it('should unpublish the asset', () => {
        spyOn(siteService, 'updateSiteAsset')
              .and.returnValue(Observable.of(objSiteAssetDetailById));

          component.publishAsset(isUndefined);
          fixture.detectChanges();
          expect(Response).toBeTruthy();
      });

    it('should cancelAsset', () => {
          component.cancelAsset();
          expect(component.isEditMode).toBe(true);
      });

    //   it('should cancelAsset', () => {
    //     component.cancelAsset();
    //    expect(component.isEditMode).toBe(false);
    //   });

    // it('should test onFileUpload', () => {
    //     component.onFileUpload();
    //    expect(component.uploadedFiles).toBeDefined();
    // });

    it('should test onFileUpload', () => {
        component.onFileUpload();
       expect(component.isLocalise).toBe(false);
   });


    it('should test getSafeUrl', () => {
        component.updatePublishedLocales('');
      expect(component.publishLocales).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should test changeAssetType', () => {
       component.changeAssetType();
      expect(component.isLocalise).toBe(false);
      expect(localiseFormData.title).toEqual('testing');

    });

    it('should test changeAssetType', () => {
        component.changeAssetTypeOfFile();
      expect(component.localesForAsset).toBeTruthy();
    });



    it('should test getAsset', () => {
        component.getAsset('');
      expect(component.hasData).toBe(false);
    }); 

    it('should test selectDataLocale', () => {
        component.selectDataLocale();
      expect(component.titleLocales).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should test selectAssetLocale', () => {
        component.selectAssetLocale();
      expect(component.assetLocales).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should test updatePublishedLocales', () => {
        component.updatePublishedLocales('');
      expect(component.publishLocales).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('should test checkPublishingLocaleStatus', () => {
        component.checkPublishingLocaleStatus('data', 'action');
        const localeArray = [] 
      expect(component.localeArray.push(name, status)).toBeTruthy();
      return localeArray;
    });

});
```

I am trying to test and coverage the statements if/else but Code coverage report showing if path not taken and the else path not taken.

I am new in Unit Test case coverage, can anyone help me how can I cover these statements.

Answer (score 1):

Each of these messages is showing that you don't have a test condition for one of the paths.  Try writing a test that calls a function and passes in the values that would resolve falsy (or truthy) for each if/else condition.  Take each message one at a time and write appropriate tests to do that.

Comment: I don't think you've looked at his question carefully.  Notice from the tests that there **is no "else" block"** hence the coverage should not be complaining

Comment: @pixelbits I did look at his question carefully.  The lack of `else` block is not the point.  If there is an `if` block, then there is implicitly more than one path depending on whether the condition returns truthy.  it will complain unless you cover both conditions (IF the block gets run or if it doesn't get run), regardless of whether or not there is an `else` block.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm encountering a similar issue.  I have an if block, with tests explicitly covering the branch.  However, there is no else block, yet its still complaining that the branch is not covered... not sure if anyone else encountered this issue.

Comment: @pixelbits make sure your tests include the if condition being truthy and also being falsy.  That should fix the complaints.

Comment: The tests should have a check for negative scenario. In the above mentioned scenario, in changeAssetType() this.localiseFormData.title[this.defaultLocale]) can have a value and you can have an assertion to check if setValue method for that form control is not called. Then it doesnt throw this code coverage error.